# SQL Server query with multiple INNER JOINs

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, inner-join

I need to execute a query that gets everything from the table `Incidents` based on a `CustomerID`. The `CustomerID` comes from the `MasterAccounts` table, which is not directly related to the `Incidents` table. There is a `SubAccounts` table that could be `INNER JOIN`-ed to relate the two.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    MasterAccounts AS ma
INNER JOIN 
    SubAccounts AS sa
INNER JOIN 
    Incidents AS i
WHERE
    ma.CustomerID = sa.CustomerID;
    AND sa.AccountID = i.AccountID
    AND IncidentTypeID = 11;
```

This is failing with

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to lookup the syntax for joins. The predicates should be on the join, not in the where clause.

Comment: You are missing `ON` clauses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define **join conditions** with `ON` after your `INNER JOIN`, to link the two tables:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    MasterAccounts AS ma
INNER JOIN 
    SubAccounts AS sa ON ma.CustomerID = sa.CustomerID;
INNER JOIN 
    Incidents AS i ON sa.AccountID = i.AccountID
WHERE
    IncidentTypeID = 11;
```

Those columns must exist in the tables involved, and should have the same datatype (because otherwise the JOIN might cause a "hidden" data type conversion which can be costly in terms of performance)

Answer (score 3):

Most of the WHERE conditions should be in ON clauses for each join:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM MasterAccounts ma
INNER JOIN SubAccounts sa ON sa.CustomerID = ma.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Incidents i ON i.AccountID = sa.AccountID
WHERE IncidentTypeID = 11;
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax would be:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    MasterAccounts AS ma
INNER JOIN 
    SubAccounts AS sa ON ma.CustomerID = sa.CustomerID;
INNER JOIN 
    Incidents AS i ON sa.AccountID = i.AccountID
WHERE 
    IncidentTypeID = 11;
```

Hope this helps!